# Mover item de array para a ultima posição!

Tags: php, array

Galera preciso mover um item de um array para a ultima posição do mesmo!
Primeiro eu ordenei ele por ordem altabetica, porem um item precisa ser o ultimo da lista, como consigo fazer isso com PHP ?
Tenho o seguinte código:

```
 foreach ( $services as $key => $service ) {
     if($service->values->group == "YubPArfPdg7phRfmyRjS") {
         echo($service->values->group);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode remover o item que você quer do array e adicioná-lo novamente (no final)

Exemplo:

```
$aux = $services[$key];
unset($services[$key]);
$services[$key] = $aux;
```

Comment: Deu certo aqui brother mais usei o array_push() msm resultado.. VLW!